# Textbf Not working

Tags: fonts

I am writing my Master Thesis in latex but I am experiencing some issues.
I am using a custom document class, linked [here](http://pastebin.com/RYzATMns)

The issue I am experiencing is that `\textbf` and `\textit` are not working. Unfortunately I do not know where to look and how to start "debugging" the issue. I do not get any errors (some warnings, though).

Could you please help me?

EDIT: an non working example. the problem seems to be the package that is used to define the title style.

```
    \documentclass{Thesis}

    \usepackage{tgtermes}


    \begin{document}



        abc\textbf{abc}


   \end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to Tex.SX! Please elaborate a bit: where are they not working? Could you provide a Minimal (Non)Working Example (see the help of this site), so we can help you?

Comment: There is nothing in the class which would disable the commands and I'm rather sure that a minimal example `\documentclass{thesis}
\begin{document}
abc\textbf{abc}
\end{document}` would work for you.

Comment: Indeed a minimal example with this class as suggested by Ulrike Fischer does work.  Please provide a MWE as requested.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer i tried what you have said and it does not work. [Here](http://pastebin.com/m8FYq9ES) there is my main with the example. I really cannot see the problem

Comment: Maybe you are using a font or font shape, where bold or italic is not available. Candidates for this kind of problems are small caps or typewriter fonts. Check the `.log` file for font warnings/substitutions.

Comment: Show the log-file and the output  of *my minimal example*  (not of your main.tex which loads a lot of additional local stuff).

Comment: The MWE works without problems. [here](http://pastebin.com/AFrB4a5J) the log of the example. While [here](http://pastebin.com/ZVjDJCWt) the log of my main

Comment: The log makes this quite clear: `LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape \`OT1/qtm/b/n' undefined
(Font)              using \`OT1/qtm/m/n' instead on input line 87.`  so your `qtm` family is not available in bold.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle ok... what does it really mean? how can I solve the issue?

Comment: It means the font is not available. However the standard ot1qtm.fd file does declare a bold font, so something odd. Make a small; complete example that you can add to ypur question that does not require linking to external files.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The OT1qtm.fd file is missing so latex falls back to cmr. One would have to install the tex gyre fonts.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer ah I didn't read the top of the log file, just jumped to the font substitution warnings.  You answer, I'll vote for you:-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your log-file says

```
LaTeX Font Info:    No file OT1qtm.fd. on input line 862.
```

LaTeX then falls back to cmr and so you are missing the bold font. 
The missing file is from the TeX-Gyre fonts. You will have to install them, or remove the code which change to this font, or add something like `\usepackage{mathptmx}` in your document to switch to another font.

Comment: I see. How can I install it? EDIT: I think that the problem is the package tgtermes, however I have the file tgtermes.sty in the same folder.

Comment: The style it self is not enough. Check with the debian tool if there are packages that sounds as if they would install the texgyre fonts. (They are in texlive 2013).

Comment: I had to install the tex-gyre package from the repositories `sudo apt-get install tex-gyre`. Now it works smoothly. Thanks