# \textbf not working properly and return the error

Tags: horizontal-alignment, bold, boldmath

I have the following code:

```
\begin{center}
    \textbf{W}  =  the player with the white dice win the game, \\ % Line 1
    \textbf{B_{i1}}  =  the red die shows i, where  i  =  1,2,3,4,5,6 % Line 2
\end{center}
```

When I remove \textbf{} from line 2 the code exits successfully other it gives the following error:

> Missing $ inserted. \textbf{B_i}
> Extra }, or forgotten $. \textbf{B_i}
> Command \end{center} invalid in math mode. \end{center}
> Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item. \end{center}
> Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item. \end{center}
> Missing $ inserted. \end{center}
> Missing } inserted. \end{center}

I have looked [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/267518/textbf-in-math-expression-returns-error)  and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/253151/textbf-not-working) but couldn't find them helpful.

Anyone, please help. Thanks in advance

Comment: `B_{i1}` needs math mode, hence the error

Comment: `\textbf` is working, the underscore `_` is the problem as it needs math mode.

Comment: @campa in this way $\textbf{B_i}$ it again shows an error. But when I use it in the following way \textbf{$B_i$} the boldface is lost. :(

Comment: `\textbf` switches to text, so you can't use `_` within its argument. Maybe you want `$\mathbf{B}_{i}$` but the intended output is not quite clear.

Comment: Thank you very much @campa

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you are looking for something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{split}
\mathbf{W}     &= \text{the player with the white dice wins the game,} \\ % Line 1
\mathbf{B}_{i} &= \text{the red die shows $i$, where $i =  1,\dotsc,6$.} % Line 2
\end{split}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

I use an unnumbered displayed equation `\[...\]` instead of a `center` environment, and align the equal signs.

`\textbf` is a macro which makes boldface *text*: if you write `\textbf{B_i}` you get an error because the underscore is allowed only in math mode; if you write `\textbf{$B_i$}` you get no error but the math is of course not bold.